# How do I get the current Date/time in DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM format?

Tags: ruby

How can I get the current date and time in `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM` format and also increment the month?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

The formatting can be done like this (I assumed you meant HH:MM instead of HH:SS, but it's easy to change):

```
Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
#=> "14/09/2011 14:09"
```

Updated for the shifting:

```
d = DateTime.now
d.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
#=> "11/06/2017 18:11"
d.next_month.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
#=> "11/07/2017 18:11"
```

You need to `require 'date'` for this btw.

Comment: yeah you are right, I mean hh:mm, and thanks so much for your answer

Comment: but how can i increment month ?

Comment: Check if you can use this gem https://rubygems.org/gems/formatted_times/

Comment: Converting to string then parsing is not ideal.

Comment: @ChuckBatson This was about shifting, not a suggestion that this was the best way to get a `Date` object. Anyway, I took your comment as an opportunity to finally update this answer for current Ruby versions.

Answer (score 32):

```
require 'date'

current_time = DateTime.now

current_time.strftime "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"
# => "14/09/2011 17:02"

current_time.next_month.strftime "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"
# => "14/10/2011 17:02"
```

Comment: I find this much simpler and more readable than the accepted solution.

Answer (score 11):

```
time = Time.now.to_s

time = DateTime.parse(time).strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

for increment decrement month use <<  >> operators

examples

```
datetime_month_before = DateTime.parse(time) << 1



datetime_month_before = DateTime.now << 1
```

Answer (score 5):

For date:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

date = Time.new
#set 'date' equal to the current date/time. 

date = date.day.to_s + "/" + date.month.to_s + "/" + date.year.to_s
#Without this it will output 2015-01-10 11:33:05 +0000; this formats it to display DD/MM/YYYY

puts date
#output the date
```

The above will display, for example, **10/01/15**

And for time

```
time = Time.new
#set 'time' equal to the current time. 

time = time.hour.to_s + ":" + time.min.to_s
#Without this it will output 2015-01-10 11:33:05 +0000; this formats it to display hour and           minute

puts time
#output the time
```

The above will display, for example, **11:33**

Then to put it together, add to the end:

```
puts date + " " + time
```